Google sheet row and column filter into another tab sheet
The following is a sample set of data in a Google sheet:

and I am attempting to filter both by column and row to view output such as:

I require the column to the right headed by "E" (Elective) to be included in the output, along with the name (column A) or any other attribute that I may choose to include, since this is a large spreadsheet and the full list of columns is not shown.
I have been attempting to use a filter in a separate tab sheet , for example =filter(Sheet3!A1:J10, Sheet3!A:A="E"), but nothing appears apart from NA
Could somebody suggest a solution?


FINAL FORMULA:
=filter(filter(Sheet3!A1:J,(scan(,Sheet3!A1:J1,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))="E")+(column(Sheet3!A1:J1)<3)), (row(Sheet3!A:A)<3)+(Sheet3!B:B="Y"))



The columns appear as required, but none of the rows  are output.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

I cannot hard code the names VON|WBS|MID . The filter has to b on the SEN='Y'
